Icons momentarily displayed as text when using radzen appearance toggle
When toggling the appearance of my .NET 9 Blazor web app using the RadzenAppearanceToggle, all icons (RadzenIcon) disappear for about a second before automatically reloading. For this second the icons are displayed as text.
Steps to reproduce

I created a new Blazor .NET 9 web app project (InteractiveAuto, with default pages)
I followed the Radzen Get-Started instructions
I added two RadzenComponents to the Home.razor

<RadzenAppearanceToggle />
<RadzenIcon Icon="home" />


After starting the website and clicking the RadzenAppearanceToggle the "home" icon is displayed as text. After about a second it will again be displayed as expected.


After a second:

My temporary solution is to include the material icons directly
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/material-icons@1.13.12/iconfont/material-icons.min.css">

and override the radzen icon font variable to use these icons:
:root {
    --rz-icon-font-family: 'Material Icons';
}

(The default value of --rz-icon-font-family is Material Symbols.)
Is there a better way to overcome this issue?

I am using Radzen Blazor for Visual Studio and it works fine in my side. Maybe you can try it.
